# Cordova / Phonegap webview running in background

Tags: cordova, webview

When using Cordova, I'm told that the web view (that is where the UI runs) does not run when the app is in the background. I'm testing the Bluetooth plugin https://github.com/randdusing/BluetoothLE on iOS. When I test it and put the app in the background, the Javascript in the webview seems to run alright. So I'm intrigued. How about Android? Any case where web view does not run when app is in the background?

Comment: How can you run it in background? I am using the same plugin, but the "scan" stops when the app goes to background.

Comment: @DeLac: I didn't know what happened but you're right. I had to keep asking for service every few seconds as a workaround. I don't know if that'll pass with the app store though.

Answer (score 0):

You can run an app in background by using the background plugin.

https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode

Comment: 1. Apple will no longer accept that, unless you happen to be using audio elsewhere.
2. It doens't really run it in background, it just keeps the foreground alive, and only for as long as it's still in the tasklist. The native background services keep running, but if the foreground is dead, despite this plugin, the events will cause an exception.